# Directus.io vs Laravel voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager, directus

I am looking for a good system where I am able to

1. customize my table with custom fields without / less php development
2. get the data by rest api out of the box
3. membership area (is there a solution for directus.io, voyager, ... ) out-of-the box? (user can register and see some pages only for members) As I understand both systems are headless cms but are there a membership system already for download? Is there a better system to this?
4. are the system recommended for building an individual CRM System (as foundation for a php developer)? any other suggestions?

Regards
ms

Answer (score 1):

If the plan is to have the platform work *as* you CRM platform, then Directus would be a great fit. You can install a blank instance, and then just add the collections/fields you want (their online demo actually has an example of some CRM features):

https://demo.directus.io/admin/#/login

The only thing that Directus doesn't have, that you mentioned, is a "Public Register" feature. But this could be a single custom page page that you build that adds users through the API. Also, Public User Registration is on their roadmap.

Comment: If there is no "Public Register" feature - is there a frontend website already as a template or do I have to build it by my own?

Comment: You could build your own, but we'll be adding the option for a public register in v9 or v10... so it will be included in the core codebase (ootb) in the next few months.

Comment: is there any news about public register?

Comment: I think I saw a PR in the works for public registration (related to SSO Domain Allow-List)... not released yet though.